# Project Multiclipboard from Ch. 8 of Automate the Boring Stuff throwing errors

Tags: python-3.x

I am going through Automate the Boring Stuff as a complete beginner to programming.

I am having issues running the code for the project "Multiclipboard" from chapter 8. My code is below:

```
import shelve
import sys
import pyperclip

mcb_shelf = shelve.open('mcb')

# Save the clipboard contents to keyword
if len(sys.argv) == 3 and sys.argv[1].lower() == 'save':
    mcb_shelf[sys.argv[2]] = pyperclip.paste()
    print(sys.argv[2] + ' saved successfully')

# Delete keyword and associated content
elif len(sys.argv) == 3 and sys.argv[1].lower() == 'delete':
    del mcb_shelf[sys.argv[2]]
    print([sys.argv[2] + ' deleted'])

elif len(sys.argv) == 2:
    # List stored keywords
    if sys.argv[1].lower() == 'list':
        pyperclip.copy(str(list(mcb_shelf.keys())))
        print('List of all keywords copied to clipboard')
    # Load content associated with chosen keyword to the clipboard
    elif sys.argv[1] in mcb_shelf:
        pyperclip.copy(mcb_shelf[sys.argv[1]])
        print(sys.argv[1] + ' loaded successfully')
    # Inform user that their input doesn't match a saved keyword
    else:
        print('That keyword doesn\'t exist - so nothing'
              'has been loaded to the clipboard')


mcb_shelf.close()
```

When I run this code, I get the below errors.

```
[main 2023-06-10T16:13:09.358Z] update#setState idle
```

```
[30792:0610/121311.895:ERROR:jump_list.cc(301)] Failed to append custom category 'Recent Folders' to Jump List due to system privacy settings.
```

```
[main 2023-06-10T16:13:11.907Z] updateWindowsJumpList#setJumpList unexpected result: customCategoryAccessDeniedError
```

```
[main 2023-06-10T16:13:14.389Z] Extension host with pid 31136 exited with code: 0, signal: unknown.
```

I tried googling what they mean individually, but I couldn't really understand what was going on.

I am running python 3.11 on VSCode on Anonconda.  I also have a .bat file with the following in the same repository as the multiclipboard script.

```
@C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\anaconda3\python.exe C:\Repository\mcb.py %*
```

Any idea what the errors mean and how to resolve? Thanks!

Comment: Did you get the multi-clipboard program in Chapter 6 to work?  This program in Chapter 8 relies on the earlier program as well as the shelve module.  Have you gotten the shelve module to work?

Comment: Hmm. The chapter 6 of the book that I have does not have a multiclipboard project. The projects in my chapter 6 are "Password Locker,"  "Adding Bullets to Wiki Markup," and "Table Printer."   I use to be able to get the Password Locker to work, but actually now it is giving me the same errors as in my original question.